# GCP Error Message - systemd-udevd

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04

Anyone have any idea if this error is severe, or can it be ignored? The VM seems to be working fine. I ran fsck on /dev/sda15, and it's OK.

GCP VM is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

```
systemd-udevd[244]: error opening ATTR{/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/virtio0/host0/target0:0:1/0:0:1:0/block/sda/sda15/queue/scheduler} for writing: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL,DR: Yes you can ignore them

Its coming from [improving_performance#Changing_I/O_schedule](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/improving_performance#Changing_I/O_scheduler)r.

The process to change I/O scheduler, depending on whether the disk is rotating or not can be automated and persist across reboots which is configurable in **/etc/udev/rules.d/60-ioschedulers.rules**

Comment: cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler returns [none] so your answer makes sense. Thanks!